# Same filter gives me different results

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this "filter" with `ng-if` working perfectly fine in my code:

```
 <li ng-if="item.qext.type == 'mashup'" data-id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in assets.extensionList">
```

But I want to twist it a little bit using:

```
<li data-id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in assets.extensionList | filter: (item.qext.type == 'mashup')">
```

in order to end up doing something like:

```
 <li data-id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in filteredMashups = assets.extensionList | filter: (item.qext.type == 'mashup')">
```

But for some reason this filter:

```
ng-repeat="item in assets.extensionList | filter: (item.qext.type == 'mashup')"
```

is not giving the same results as this one:

```
ng-if="item.qext.type == 'mashup'"
```

Why?

Comment: Use `filter:{item : {qext : {type : 'mashup'}}}:true` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but seems not working... Returns an empty array.

Comment: Works perfectly for me with AngularJS 1.4.0.

Comment: Still using 1.2. Compatibility reasons... Thanks anyway! ;)

Comment: Remove the last parameter (`:true`), then ;-).

Comment: I also tried that but not working either for some reason. Returns me an empty array. I know it should work but...it doesn't!

Comment: Finally I created a function. I really wanted to make it work but I can't spend more time on that! Thanks Blackhole for your help anyway! ;)